# How to Include contents of a second package in war file using maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a Java (spring) project with the SRC/MAIN/JAVA folder containing the following packages:

```
src
|
+--main
   |
   +--java
      |
      +--com.test.me
      |
      +--org.dependency.files
```

When I run a mvn:package command the generated war file contains the **com.test.me** but does not contain **org.dependency.files** please guide on how to include the contents of **org.dependency.files** also in the generated WAR.

The Pom.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>me</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>me</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <HikariCP.version>2.3.7</HikariCP.version>
        <assertj-core.version>1.6.1</assertj-core.version>
        <awaitility.version>1.4.0</awaitility.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <gatling-maven-plugin.version>2.1.5</gatling-maven-plugin.version>
        <gatling.version>2.1.5</gatling.version>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
        <json-path.version>0.9.1</json-path.version>
        <liquibase-hibernate4.version>3.5</liquibase-hibernate4.version>
        <liquibase-slf4j.version>1.2.1</liquibase-slf4j.version>
        <liquibase.version>3.3.2</liquibase.version>
        <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>1.3.1</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
        <maven-sortpom-plugin.version>2.3.0</maven-sortpom-plugin.version>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <metrics-spark-reporter.version>1.2</metrics-spark-reporter.version>
        <metrics-spring.version>3.0.4</metrics-spring.version>
        <run.addResources>false</run.addResources>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>2.3</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <spring-security.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <swagger-springmvc.version>0.9.5</swagger-springmvc.version>
        <tomcat.version>7.0.62</tomcat.version>
        <usertype-core.version>3.2.0.GA</usertype-core.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
            <artifactId>languagetool-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.languagetool</groupId>
            <artifactId>language-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>${awaitility.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>${json-path.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-springmvc.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>scalap</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mattbertolini</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6_g</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ryantenney.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${metrics-spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>metrics-healthchecks</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
            <version>${HikariCP.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- The HikariCP Java Agent is disabled by default, as it is experimental
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP-agent</artifactId>
            <version>${HikariCP.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>embedmongo-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard-metrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-graphite</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-healthchecks</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard-metrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-json</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard-metrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard-metrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard-metrics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlets</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>metrics-healthchecks</artifactId>
                    <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongeez</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongeez</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-loader-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-localconfig-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>copy</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.2.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>java</goal>
                                            <goal>exec</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.sortpom</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-sortpom-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-sortpom-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sort</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sortProperties>true</sortProperties>
                    <nrOfIndentSpace>4</nrOfIndentSpace>
                    <sortDependencies>groupId,artifactId</sortDependencies>
                    <sortPlugins>groupId,artifactId</sortPlugins>
                    <keepBlankLines>true</keepBlankLines>
                    <expandEmptyElements>false</expandEmptyElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gatling-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configFolder>src/test/gatling/conf</configFolder>
                    <dataFolder>src/test/gatling/data</dataFolder>
                    <resultsFolder>target/gatling/results</resultsFolder>
                    <bodiesFolder>src/test/gatling/bodies</bodiesFolder>
                    <simulationsFolder>src/test/gatling/simulations</simulationsFolder>
                    <!-- This will force Gatling to ask which simulation to run
                         This is useful when you have multiple simulations -->
                    <simulationClass>*</simulationClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireMavenVersion>
                            <message>You are running an older version of Maven. JHipster requires at least Maven 3.0</message>
                            <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
                        </requireMavenVersion>
                        <requireJavaVersion>
                            <message>You are running an older version of Java. JHipster requires at least JDK ${java.version}</message>
                            <version>[${java.version}.0,)</version>
                        </requireJavaVersion>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx256m</argLine>
                    <!-- Force alphabetical order to have a reproducible build -->
                    <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                        <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                        <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                        <version>${liquibase-hibernate4.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                    <driver />
                    <url />
                    <defaultSchemaName />
                    <username />
                    <password />
                    <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:com.test.me.domain?dialect=</referenceUrl>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <logging>debug</logging>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>localdev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--spring.profiles.active=localdev</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.trecloux</groupId>
                        <artifactId>yeoman-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-frontend-build</id>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <buildTool>gulp</buildTool>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <yeomanProjectDirectory>${project.basedir}</yeomanProjectDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp/dist</directory>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>.tmp</directory>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>node_modules</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>INFO</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>fast</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--spring.profiles.active=dev,fast</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>DEBUG</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.trecloux</groupId>
                        <artifactId>yeoman-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-frontend-build</id>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <buildTool>gulp</buildTool>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <yeomanProjectDirectory>${project.basedir}</yeomanProjectDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.5</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>src/main/webapp/dist</directory>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>.tmp</directory>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>node_modules</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>--spring.profiles.active=prod</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <!-- log configuration -->
                <logback.loglevel>INFO</logback.loglevel>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```